# unget потока istream возвращает только последнюю цифру числа

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
vector<int> numbers;
vector<string> strings;
string temp;
int tempint;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
string str;
ifstream ifstr("text.txt");

while (ifstr >> temp) {
    if (isdigit(temp[0])) {
        ifstr.clear();
        ifstr.unget();
        ifstr >> tempint;
        numbers.push_back(tempint);
    }
    else {  
        strings.push_back(temp);
    }
}
ifstr.close();
for (int i : numbers) {
    cout << i << " ";
}

cout << endl;

for (string i : strings) {
    cout << i << " ";
}

cout << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Функция [`unget()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/unget) возвращает **только последний считанный символ**.

Более того, стандарт гарантирует возврат **только одного** символа. Т.е. если вы вызовите `unget()` десять раз - нет никакой уверенности, что в поток будут возвращено более 1 символа.

Как сказано в *"Стандартной библиотеку С++"* Джосаттиса, *"Стандарт гарантирует правильность работы только одного вызова между двумя операциями чтения"*.